# How to prevent users from viewing Azure SQL database tables with query editor

Tags: azure-sql-database

Is it possible to prevent users from viewing certain tables from within Azure Query editor?

With SSMS I can prevent users from viewing certain Azure SQL database tables if users are accessing the Azure SQL tables from their PC.

However, if users attempt to access the tables from within Azure Portal using the query editor, they can view the tables. Is it possible apply the same restrictions? ie prevent users from viewing the tables from with the Portal?

My thoughts are that as long as the user is a member of the Microsoft Entra admin group, see image they will always be able to view the tables using Query editor, is that correct.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you can't trust the Admin, who can you trust? Besides that, with such access can't they also create and download a BACPAC?

Comment: So, my question is that if the user isn't a member of the Entra Admin, they won't be able to view the tables, correct?

Comment: I'm curious how you think you're doing that with SSMS?

Comment: It’s quite easy, but I will have to show you in the morning as it’s very late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to prevent users from viewing Azure SQL database tables with query editor.

When we use query editor there is no way to prevent users to vives tables or hide them from whoever does not have access.

Instead of this you can deny permission to the particular user on particular table so he will not be able to see the data when you add the group to Microsoft entra admin all the members of it will inherit the same permissions.

```sql
GRANT SELECT ON "schema name"."table name" TO "user name"
```